# When is a C++ class considered big?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, memory

Specifically, suppose one's working on a 64-bit machine and there's a class A whose output of `sizeof` is *N*.

Is there any agreement as to what the value of *N* is beyond which one should use pointers when including class A as a data member of another class B?

Comment: Basically never? The big arrays that could increase the size are usually `std::vector`s themselves, already on the heap.

Comment: Only for the stack, where space is much more limited.  Visual Studio now complains / warns you about any allocation over 16K.

Comment: Some people say that if a class doesn't fit on a "page", it is too big.

Comment: When choosing between pass-by-value or pass-by-const-reference, "big" is >512 bytes on my platform.  But that will vary by platform architecture.

Comment: The definition of "big" is relative to what the class is intended to do.   Some folks consider, for example, `std::vector` to be a big class, since it provides a boatload of functionalities.   But, not everyone quibbles over its size, and some even lobby for additional capabilities (implying, at the least, it is not "too big", whatever that means) since it is a generic container that enables a significant number of use-cases, and provides flexibility to programmers whos needs and choices cannot be anticipated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its entirely subjective, and depends on the work needed. A string-like class should probably be less than 4 pointers, about ~32 bytes. A large data analysis class could be a thousand bytes, and I wouldn't blink an eye.

In general, subjectively, the thresholds I keep an eye on are:

1. Many common cpu cache lines are 64 bytes. A class larger than that will be slower than a class smaller than that. And a *lot* of classes are <=64 bytes.  In general, if a class is <=64 bytes, I probably won't even think about it's size, and if it's >64 bytes, I'll think about it for a while.
2. Many common cpu page sizes are 4096 bytes. A class larger than that that is hanging around in dynamic memory for a while may have parts of itself paged to disk, which makes it *really* slow, and needing that much space, is super suspicious. Usually, one would have a smaller class that manages a large *array* in dynamic memory instead.